# Python Xls writer: Is there any way to write 1400 columns in excel file?

Tags: python, xls, xlsxwriter

I can write `1024` column with [xlsxwriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter) module with .xlsx extension. Actually I'm viewing in libreOffice calc. Not sure whether it is a problem with that. It shows only `1024` column. Is there any way to write `1400` column in excel file? I'm not allowed to split those column. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

XlsxWriter supports Excel's limits of 1,048,576 rows and 16,384 columns per worksheet.

However, the version of LibreOffice on my system, 3.6.7.2, only supports 1024 columns. So that is probably the source of your issue.

Update: Here is a LibreOffice [bug report](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50916&redirected_from=fdo) that says it only supports 1024 columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any way to validate that more than 1024 columns are written in my .xlsx file? Any known xlsx reader will be a great help. Again thanks for your effort

Comment: I'll try not to be disappointed that you didn't take my word for it (or the unit tests that I wrote to validate cell ranges in XlsxWriter). :-) You could open the file in Excel or use xlrd to read it. If the data isn't there I'll give you your money back.

Answer (score 0):

You can write as many as columns and rows using Python win32Com.